# Accessing dropped item with jQuery/Ember framework

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, ember.js, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using the ember.js and jQuery-ui frameworks. Currently, I am able to get elements to be draggable and can fire an event when the item is dropped into a specific div.

However, I am not able to get the actual element that was dropped onto the div. The event variable passed in represents the div that the element was dropped onto and 'this' represents a ember object.

How am I able to access the item that was dropped?

Overview of the code I am using:

```
App.MyView = Em.View.extend({
    ...
    drag: function (event) {
        // This works correctly and the event here represents the actual element
        console.log("Dragging");
    },
    drop: function (event) {
        // This is where I am not able to access the dropped iem
        console.log("Dropped");
    },
    ...
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery draggable/droppable, `ui.draggable` should be what you're looking for.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop

`drop: function(event, ui) { ... }`

> In the callback, $(this) represents the droppable the draggable is dropped on. ui.draggable represents the draggable.